# Maven Settings XML Plugin

Tags: maven, plugins

I have numerous tests which need to be ran on a websphere web server, before each test I want to restart the server. In my test projects pom I can use:

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                            <id>startServer</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>start.bat</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

The issue here being that I have multiple projects, each with profiles for various functionality. I want to move this into the maven settings.xml so that the profiles are transparent to the individual tests and only ever ran based on environment variables provided by jenkins.

It seems as though I can not use plugins in the maven settings xml. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This can't be moved to settings.xml file. Do you have a corporate pom or a project parent pom?

Comment: unfortunately not, it seems that (for now) I will have to put the multiple profiles in the pom of each project. It is a simple solution my boss is happy with

Comment: Start create a corporate pom or a within a multi module build within the parent...which is really important. The corporate pom should contain the plugins with their versions etc.